# Proving results on quadratic equations

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing, proof-explanation, contest-math, quadratics

> Let $p \in \mathbb Z [x]$ be a monic quadratic polynomial. Show that for $n \in \mathbb Z$ there exists $k \in \mathbb Z$ such that $$p(n)p(n+1)=p(k)$$

I came across this problem in an olympiad book. I have tried this question by many different approaches like simply putting $n , (n+1)$ into the quadratic equation and and try to factorise or do something to get the result but it doesn't help. Secondly, I know that

$$p(x)-p(n)p(n+1)=0$$

has a root equal to $k$ and then there is only one thing left to do that is to prove k integer which we can prove by proving discriminant to be a perfect square and other coefficients as integer but the problem arises how to prove discriminant to be a perfect square. Please tell if either of these approaches will take us to the prove or if not please tell the correct steps of proving

I am very confused with problem (not a homework problem). Please help to prove it with proper steps and methods.

Comment: You have a good question with a lot of context, but your question needs more punctuation to make it more readable.

Comment: Do we have to prove this statement for any $p(x)$ or just one specific $p(x)$?

Comment: For  Any $p(x)$ we have to prove

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write $p(x)=x^2+ax+b$.

**Solution #$1$:**

The intuition is that it's probably an algebraic identity.

Since $p(x)p(x+1)$ expands to a monic polynomial of degree $4$, it makes sense to look for an identity of the form
$$p(x)p(x+1)=p(x^2+cx+d)$$
Expanding and equating coefficients, we get $c=a+1$ and $d=b$, which yields the verifiable identity
$$p(x)p(x+1)=p(x^2+(a+1)x+b)$$

**Solution #$2$:**

As an alternative method, we can follow through with your approach . . .

Fix an integer $n$.

Our goal is to show that the quadratic equation
$$p(x)=p(n)p(n+1)$$
has an integer solution for $x$.

Equivalently, we want to show that the discriminant $D$ is a perfect square.

Computing $D$, we get
\begin{align*}
D&=
4n^4\\[2pt]
&{\phantom{=}}\;+(8+8a)n^3\\[2pt]
&{\phantom{=}}\;+(4a^2+12a+8b+4)n^2\\[2pt]
&{\phantom{=}}\;+(4a^2+8ab+4a+8b)n\\[2pt]
&{\phantom{=}}\;+(a^2+4ab+4b^2)\\[6pt]
&=\bigl(2n^2+(2a+2)n+(a+2b)\bigr)^2
\end{align*}